# Can I show that a map is linear before I show it is well-defined?

Tags: functions, modules

I am trying to define a linear map of R-modules which involves showing it is both well-defined and R-linear. I think I managed to prove both of these, although I realized I proved linearity first, and then used it in the proof of well-definedness.

Is this sort of thing allowed? The definition of linearity uses that of a function, so I'm not so sure.

Edit: I wasn't sure how relevant details of my actual proof are, so I left them out. But, I'll say that I was able to show it was linear first because I defined the map in terms of another linear map (trying to force a diagram to commute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not a matter of being "allowed" or not.  All that matters is whether your logic is valid.  When you are talking about a "function" which you have not yet proved is well-defined, that really means you are talking about a *relation* or "multi-valued function" that can have multiple possible outputs for a given input.  As long as you formulate everything in a way that makes sense in this context, you're fine.

For instance, given a multi-valued function $f:X\to Y$, you might prove it is "linear" in the sense that if $a,b\in X$ and $c$ is a value of $f(a)$ and $d$ is a value of $f(b)$, then $c+d$ is a value of $f(a+b)$.  Indeed, this is the sort of statement you would typically be able to prove if elements of $X$ were defined as equivalence classes and $f$ was defined by choosing representatives of equivalence classes.  You could then potentially use this "linearity" property to prove $f$ is well-defined.